# What is the total amount of database queries Joomla does on a request with cache disabled?

Tags: php, mysql, joomla

Thats about my question, I want to know how many db queries is done on a request when cache is disabled.

Thanks :)

Comment: The answer is **42**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enable the debug mode from Global configuration.
This will show you all queries that were logged during the last request.

Last request mean, if there are multiple redirection, then it will show the queries of last redirection(request).

Answer (score 0):

That depends on the backend code (server side application code). Nobody will be able to tell you this (except the one that wrote the backend code).

**Example:** I use my browser to call a website.
In order to display the site i do not know if there is a db-query involved at all to create the HTML code of the page.
But it might be that on the backend some very expensive db operations take place. The user will never know. Only the persons involved in the backend process might be able to find out how many queries are necessary.